# Find files in unknown directory

Tags: directory

I want to find a file in an unknown directory and then chmod it. Could you help with that please?
So far I wrote 
    find . -type f -name ".pdf" chmod {};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the man page of `find` command says that in order to execute a command (in this case `chmod`) to matching file the command need to be specified using `-exec` parameter

```
find . -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec chmod 744 {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! However, wouldn't this change the permission for all the .pdf files that there are in my computer? I only want it to change the permission for the files inside the mainDir directory/inside the random subdirectory that the user chooses. Cheers

Comment: @Alec Find command will search for files in all subfolder in the current directory. If you want, you can change the '.' to any directory you want. For example `find /home/user/app -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec chmod 744 {} \;` will search for all PDF in the `/home/user/app directory` and it's subdirectory

Comment: @Jim6834 please add the information from your first comment above to your question